# Export to PDF/Excel a html table and after attach to email

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a store procedure that send an email with a htmltable every time a person is about to complete a year on a department, so the recipients know they need to rotate the personal.

Now i want to convert that table a pdf or excel file to attach it to the email. How can i convert my htmltable to pdf/excel?

Sorry bad english.

Comment: We can work with a language variance. But you don't have a question here. Just a vague description of a process requirement.

Comment: @SeanLange edited

Comment: Still incredibly vague. There are so many ways to do this. I would do it in c# and not in a stored procedure. Or maybe SSIS. But there just isn't any context here to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange and now?

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail is quite limited. SQL Server is really just sending text, even formatted as HTML.

Your options are to send the data as a CSV which would then open in Excel, or otherwise to find an external function which would allow you to encode the data in PDF or Excel format to provide as the attachment.

An alternative would be for your SPROC to trigger an SSIS package that would use the Excel export task to convert your data to an excel file. That could then be sent on as an attached document.

Another possibility is to use SSRS and create a data driven subscription report that saves in PDF format...